# How can I send different request in intercepter?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, axios

I'm trying to send different request in interceptor

I want to send accessToken in request header authorization for every request except one case

so I write this code in interceptor request.use

```js
config.headers = {authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`};
```

but if this error occurred

```js
error.response.data.code === 'expired'
```

I want to send `refreshtoken` in header authorization not `accesstoken`

so I write this code in interceptor.response.use.error

```js
const { data } = await axios.post(
  `${Config.API_URL}/user/refreshToken`,
  {},
  { headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${refreshToken}` } }
);
```

this is my code

```js
useEffect(() => {
  axios.interceptors.request.use(async (config: any) => {
    const accessToken = await EncryptedStorage.getItem("accessToken");
    config.headers = { authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` };
    return config;
  });

  axios.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
      return response;
    },
    async (error) => {
      const {
        config,
        response: { status },
      } = error;
      if (status === 419) {
        if (error.response.data.code === "expired") {
          const originalRequest = config;
          const refreshToken = await EncryptedStorage.getItem("refreshToken");
          const { data } = await axios.post(
            `${Config.API_URL}/user/refreshToken`,
            {},
            { headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${refreshToken}` } }
          );
          return axios(originalRequest);
        }
      }
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );
}, [dispatch]);
```

how can i fix my code?
if i use my code if error.response.data.code === 'expired'

the headers.authorization accesstoken is still being requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it so your request interceptor only sets a default `authorization` header without overriding anything already present

```ts
axios.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
  const accessToken = await EncryptedStorage.getItem("accessToken");
  return {
    ...config,
    headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      ...config.headers
    }
  }
});
```

You could also avoid making the `getItem()` request entirely which might save a little time

```js
axios.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
  if (!config.headers.authorization) {
    config.headers.authorization = `Bearer ${await EncryptedStorage.getItem("accessToken")}`
  }
  return config;
});
```

Comment: what do you mean place this _after_ `authorization`?

Comment: Exactly like in my answer. The current `config.headers` go _after_ the `authorization` header with the `accessToken`. That way, any request that already had an `authorization` header value will overwrite the default. I've removed that comment since it obviously wasn't very clear

Comment: thank you! so much so if i do that when (error.response.data.code === "expired")  this error occured,  header value which is refreshtoken  will overwrite accesstoken!
Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: @user15322469 that's correct

Comment: Sorry, I'm really not sure what you mean. Catching errors is more of a response interceptor job